# How get values from simplexml_load_file() in php?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, object

I am getting an XML response from an api.Here is the code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($actualurl);
    echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
    echo '</pre>';
```

The output will look like this

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [MERCHANT] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [RESPONSE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [url] => https://xxx/xxx/epi/fts
                    [param] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => NBFundTransfer
                            [1] => 354206
                            [2] => fhyF1K5nmhXJmhoIUb04%2BEiIe80rLda52l4bCviNPwg%3D
                            [3] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Problem I cant get the node  values of `param` array.I tried `$xml->param` but it shows nothing returns an empty value.

Comment: edit with the content of your xml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
print_r($xml->MERCHANT->RESPONSE->param[0]);
```

Comment: How can get each param value?

Comment: By param index 
`$xml->MERCHANT->RESPONSE->param[0],
$xml->MERCHANT->RESPONSE->param[1]
`

Comment: I cant understand please provide a detailed answer

Comment: please provide me your `$actualurl`

Answer (score 0):

```
    print_r($xml->MERCHANT->RESPONSE->param);

    $param = $xml->MERCHANT->RESPONSE->param;
    echo $param[0]; //=> NBFundTransfer
 echo '<br>';
    echo $param[1]; // => 354206
 echo '<br>';
    echo $param[2]; // => fhyF1K5nmhXJmhoIUb04%2BEiIe80rLda52l4bCviNPwg%3D
 echo '<br>';
    echo $param[3]; // => 1
```